# jupyter note book in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Whenever I start the Kernel, this warning pop up [image]

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2202: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' if you require traitlets >=5.
  warn(
c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2157: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use '650acb8e-de88-49d4-83a0-12cbf7a674c3' instead of 'b"650acb8e-de88-49d4-83a0-12cbf7a674c3"'.
  warn(
Bad file descriptor (bundled\zeromq\src\epoll.cpp:100).
```

How do I deal with whis issue?

Comment: I'd start from updating jupyter and ipython: `pip install --upgrade jupyter ipython`

Comment: A really quick google search suggest the approach @Marat recommended, did you try that?

Comment: @Marat It still fail. I've try some of the solution on the google, but they don't wrok. : (

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by install a lower version of pyzmq by:

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq==19.0.2
```